# loginviewcontroller before the tabviewcontroller which includes SideMenuController

Tags: iphone, ios6, storyboard

[image: Following the storyboard]

**Problem:** I have a tabViewController which includes four tabs and at the 1st tab is the homeViewController **which includes sideMenuViewController**.Now I want to add loginViewController before tabViewController which is only one time login .currently.my app is working properly without loginViewController and following is the below code in AppDelegate.m class .

```
Now I want to include loginViewController before the tabViewController
```

please suggest me the necessary changes in my AppDelegate.m

**AppDelegate.m**

```
 (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
tabBarController = (UITabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];


        MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)tabBarController.viewControllers [0];
        NSParameterAssert ([container isKindOfClass: [MFSideMenuContainerViewController class]]);
    //    UIViewController *historycontr=(UIViewController *)tabBarController.viewControllers[2];
    //    UIViewController *hist=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"historyController"];
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationController"];
        UIViewController *leftSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftSideMenuViewController"];
        UIViewController *rightSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rightSideMenuViewController"];

        [container setLeftMenuViewController:leftSideMenuViewController];
        [container setRightMenuViewController:rightSideMenuViewController];
        [container setCenterViewController:navigationController];



        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: First edit formation of your Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull on a new UIViewController that will act as the login view controller onto the MainStoryboard. In the attribute inspector change the identifier to LoginViewController (or something appropriate)

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];

      UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
      UIViewController *login = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
      [vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

      [self presentModalViewController:login animated:YES];
}
```

after successful login just dismiss LoginViewController

Check this [Example](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0AGzQqxBZ9CYXpJT3dlTUd2M2c/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for swift reply .. By doing this I can see the FirstViewcontroller then later it animates and display loginviewcontroller , Can it be possible to view only LoginViewcontroller ? and its displaying Warning: Attempt to present <loginpageViewController: 0xa114b30> on <UITabBarController: 0xa12b730> while a presentation is in progress!

Comment: Thanks I did Animation:No , Can you please tell me about why the warning ?

Comment: Try this  ` [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:login animated:YES completion:nil];` in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** where login is your `loginpageViewController`

Comment: have you check you have write code in `viewDidAppear` method?